# I2C HAL_I2C_Master_Receive

Tags: c, i2c

I want to use i2c in C language and read the red square value using the register at the bottom of the red

It doesn't work well.

How can I read it?

I used the code below, but it didn't work well, so how should I modify it?

I know you did something wrong because it was a completely different price, but there's nothing coming out

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnpF5.png)

code

```
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

#define test1  (0xfe)

uint8_t a[1];

HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, test1, a, 2, 50);
printf("check1 : %04X\n\r", a[0]);
```

Comment: Is this for STM32? If so you should add the [tag:stm32] and [tag:embedded] tags to the question.

Answer (score 0):

At least this problem.

Code is lying to [`HAL_I2C_Master_Receive()`](http://www.disca.upv.es/aperles/arm_cortex_m3/llibre/st/STM32F439xx_User_Manual/group__i2c__exported__functions__group2.html#ga6b3cef8c309e88ed6d3b8deba149aac9) with the 2 as the sizeof the buffer given `uint8_t a[1];`.

Instead:

```
uint8_t a[2];  // size 2

HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(
    &hi2c1, test1, a, sizeof a, 50);
```

Tip: also check return status.